nginx domain redirect not working for HTTPS!
I have two domains my-example.com and myexample.com and for each a sub-domain www.my-example.com and www.myexample.com.
Now, I want nginx to redirect requests to myexample.com to my-example.com respectively www.myexample.com to my-example.com.
That configuration is working fine as long as I use HTTP (:80) but as I try to request it with HTTPS, nginx always redirects to the default server, with the default ssl certificate (which is not my-example.com) and not just redirects.
My config looks like this:
server {
    listen                              80;
    listen                              [::]:80;
    server_name                         myexample.com www.myexample.com;
    
    location / {
        return 301 https://my-example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen                              443 ssl;
    listen                              [::]:443 ssl;
    http2                               on;
    server_name                         myexample.com www.myexample.com;

    location / {
        return 301 https://my-example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

Thanks for your help.

Your example config is wrong. The second server block is redirecting to myexample.com.

Edited: did a mistake in the redirect for this post. But that was not the original issue. Thanks, @Richard Smith, for pointing this out.

The config in your question does not install any certificates and you do not show the full configuration. You should probably add the output of nginx -T (uppercase T) and an example curl command that illustrates the specific problem.

What the others said, but your first 301 should use https://$host$request_uri; instead of hard coding the hostname if you want it to redirect to the respective hostname. Also you are using myexample and my-example, so you need to clarify which is correct or add the missing config.


NEVER use a 301 redirect until you have the desired behaviour using 302 redirects; 301 redirects are cached indefinitely by your browser 2) Did you check the sequence of events using curl or with developer tools?

